# How to end a script submitted by "at" starting new processes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, top, at

I started a script on a server using "at":
    `at now < script.sh`
My problem is, that the script repeatedly starts new processes. Is it possible to stop the whole script instead of killing the single processes using "top"? I can not find the running script using "top", "bg" or "ps aux". I could not find a solution using google, only solutions to kill foreground jobs are offered.

Killing the process id `at now < script.sh &` spills out does not work either:

```
user@linux:$ at now < script.sh &
[1] 16428
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
user@linux:$ job 3 at Sat Sep 10 11:58:00 2016

[1]+  Fertig                  at now < script.sh
user@linux:$ kill 16428
bash: kill: (16428) - Kein passender Prozess gefunden
```

"Kein passender Prozess gefunden" means "no matching process found".

Comment: What if you did `at now < script.sh &` and killed the PID it spits out?

Comment: The `at` program just submits your commands for execution and exits immediately, so its pid is useless; the execution is done by a different process(es). While running it(they) _should_ show in BSD-style `ps ax` but might be easier to find if you use ATT-style `ps -fu yourusernameornumber` and focus on the entries with `?` under `TTY`.

Comment: you confuse `&` ( background job/process in same shell ) and `at` (detached shell). I would advise to use either `at now < script.sh` or `script.sh &` depending on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dave_thompson_085 is correct with his comment. Using `ps -fu yourusernameornumber` I could find the script's processes (including PID) called "sh". I could stop them by `kill <PID>`.